# NotSupportedException error when PInvoking DLL function

Tags: c#, c++

I am using a DLL file with a function called ExecCommand(). The C++ header fine define this function as:

```
    _NFC_EXPORT_ ResponseMsg * WINAPI ExecCommand(Commands pCmd, ...);
```

The return value is a structure also define in the header file as:

```
    typedef struct _ResponseMsg 
    {
    int status;
    int length;
    BYTE data[APDU_LEN];
    BOOL statuswords;
    BYTE sw1;
    BYTE sw2;

    TCHAR errorMsg[MAX_PATH];

    } ResponseMsg;
```

The parameter "Commands pCmd" is an enum.

I tried accessing this function in a c# program using PInvoke:

```
    [DllImport("\\Windows\\NFC_DLL.dll", EntryPoint = "ExecCommand")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    public static extern ResponseMsg ExecCommand(
        Commands pCmd, 
        params byte[] pParam
        );
```

I defined the ResponseMsg as:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential), Serializable]
    public struct ResponseMsg
    {
        public int status;
        public int length;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 255)]
        public byte[] data;

        public bool statuswords;
        public byte sw1;
        public byte sw2;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
        public string errorMsg;
    }
```

During execution, I keep getting the NotSupportedException error. Can you spot the error in my c# code? Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't the exception have some more information about it? And as far as I know MAX_PATH is 260, not 100.

Comment: The *params* keyword is the problem.  Check [this blog post](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/28/4473.aspx) to see how to use the undocumented __arglist keyword in C#.  The struct isn't going to return well either, you have to declare the return type as IntPtr and marshal it yourself with Marshal.PtrToStructure().  Then you are going to have to fret about getting the memory released again, that's going to be difficult.  Really rather best to write this code in C++/CLI.

Comment: @Dirk This is the only information i got. As for MAX_PATH, I think the DLL limits the size to 100.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried using the __arglist keyword. Now it is giving me the "MissingMethodException" pointing at "Application.Run(new Form1());" in the Program.cs file.

Comment: BTW, i am working on a compact framework.

Comment: This is what I did: I created different P/Invoke of the same function giving the required number of parameter(s) as I needed it.

[DllImport("NFC_DLL.dll", EntryPoint = "ExecCommand")]
public static extern IntPtr ExeCom1(Commands pCmd);

[DllImport("NFC_DLL.dll", EntryPoint = "ExecCommand")]
public static extern IntPtr ExeCom2(Commands pCmd,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] byte pParam1
);

[DllImport("NFC_DLL.dll", EntryPoint = "ExecCommand")]
public static extern IntPtr ExeCom3(Commands pCmd,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] byte pParam1,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] byte pParam2
);